# How to find all events with the related workshops?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have two tables. One is "Event" and another is "Workshop". Here, the table workshop has an attribute "eventId" which is defined like:

```
  @Column({
    type: 'integer',
    defaultValue: null,
  } as ModelAttributeColumnOptions)
  eventId: number;
```

Now I want to get all the events with the related workshops in a **single query** and **no post-processing of the results**. How can I achieve this using sequelize?

My another question is do I have to create an association between two tables for this? Can i get the result just by comparisons?

I've tried to do it like:

```js
const eventsWithWorkshops = await Event.findAll({
      include: [
        {
          model: Workshop,
          where: {
            eventId: Sequelize.col('event.id')
          },
        }
      ]
    });

    // Log the result to console
    console.log(eventsWithWorkshops);
    return eventsWithWorkshops;
```

Sadly, it throws 500 exception.

Output should be like:

````json
    [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Laravel convention 2021',
        createdAt: '2021-04-25T09:32:27.000000Z',
        workshops: [
          {
            id: 1,
            start: '2021-02-21 10:00:00',
            end: '2021-02-21 16:00:00',
            eventId: 1,
            name: 'Illuminate your knowledge of the laravel code base',
            createdAt: '2021-04-25T09:32:27.000000Z',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Laravel convention 2023',
        createdAt: '2023-04-25T09:32:27.000000Z',
        workshops: [
          {
            id: 2,
            start: '2023-10-21 10:00:00',
            end: '2023-10-21 18:00:00',
            eventId: 2,
            name: 'The new Eloquent - load more with less',
            createdAt: '2021-04-25T09:32:27.000000Z',
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            start: '2023-11-21 09:00:00',
            end: '2023-11-21 17:00:00',
            eventId: 2,
            name: 'AutoEx - handles exceptions 100% automatic',
            createdAt: '2021-04-25T09:32:27.000000Z',
          },
        ],
      },
    ]
    ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all create the associations in Event model like:

```
Event.hasMany(Workshop, { foreignKey: "eventId", as: "workshops" });
Workshop.belongsTo(Event, { foreignKey: "eventId", as: "event" });
```

Then sequelize query will be like:

```
    const eventsWithWorkshops = await Event.findAll({
      include: [
         {
            model: Workshop,
            as: "workshops"
         }
      ],
      where: {
        id: Number(eventId) // if you want to fetch all workshops for specific event, then put where clause, else remove the where clause and you will get all events with related workshops
      },
   });
    
   // Log the result to console
   console.log(eventsWithWorkshops);
   return eventsWithWorkshops;
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: I suppose `belongsTo` should go with a singular alias `as: "event"` instead of `as: "events"`

Comment: Yes, but if you follow the convention, it will be the name of db table, which is always in plural. :)

Comment: We know that these aliases turn into props in the loaded models so if you see `events` prop you definitely assume that its ab object/array that stores information about SEVERAL events and not about a single one. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, you are right, we can also make singular for better representation as well. Thanks! :)